# Apache RedirectMatch not Working as Expected

Tags: apache, redirect, virtualhost

I want to match a set of subfolders and redirect them to the appropriate subdomain. Note, there is a wildcard domain extension. I want it to work with multiple TLD such as `.com` or `.ca`.

```
RedirectMatch "^example\.(.*)/(article|company)/" "https://$2.example.$1"
```

**Examples:**

```
https://example.com/article/test-article → https://article.example.com/test-article
https://example.ca/article/test-article-ca → https://article.example.com/test-article-ca
https://example.com/company/test-company → https://company.example.com/test-company
```

Is this possible with **RedirectMatch**? What is wrong with one I made?